UI not showing operation summary and description
I use quarkus-bom 3.6.9
I used the Operation annotation in order to have summary and description in the swagger ui
@Operation(operationId = "findTornateByRevId11",
                summary = "My summray",
                description ="Extended description",
                responses = { @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Risposta di tutte le tornate della revisione",content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = TornataListResponse.class))),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "0", description = "Errore sul sistema",
                 content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ApiError.class))) })
    public Response findTornateByRevId(@PathParam("revId") BigInteger revId,@Context SecurityContext securityContext, 

But in the swagger-ui summary and description are not visible. I declare two different types of respose but in the swagger-ui there is only one.
I also generate a yaml file with maven
<plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputFileName>myt</outputFileName>
          <outputPath>src/main/resources/yaml/</outputPath>
          <templateDirectory>src/main/resources/codegen/api</templateDirectory>
          <outputFormat>YAML</outputFormat>
          <resourcePackages>            
            <package>it.scam.myt.backend</package>
          </resourcePackages>
          <prettyPrint>TRUE</prettyPrint>
          <sortOutput>TRUE</sortOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resolve</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>  

and in this this generated file I've summary and description and the two differnt types of response.
So I think it could be something about quarkus dev swagger ui. Any idea?
